# Search for value(s) in meta field for a multi select

Tags: meta-query

So, we used to have this user meta field that stored a single ID to a post.
I'm working on rewriting it so it can have multiple IDs to posts. So a single user can have multiple posts in that field.
This all works, shows and stores correctly.

I had:

```
                $meta_query = array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'meta_field',
                        'value' => $value,
                        'compare' => '='
                    ),
                );
```

Which worked.
How do I now search for example post ID '25688' in a meta field that is

```
"a:2:{i:0;s:5:"25688";i:1;s:5:"26974";}"
```

in DB.

I guess I could do a LIKE, but that seems prone to errors once you tick up a digit. Also won't allow me to search for multiple values at once like an IN would allow me to do.

This doesn't seem to be complicated, but has me stumped.

Comment: This is the problem with serialized data, it's difficult to search through because it tends to return a lot of false positives.  :-(  Consider adding the posts as an array rather than serialized or allowing multiple entries of the same meta_field per user.

Comment: @TonyDjukic Unfortunately, I'm not that well-versed with Wordpress. I found a Select2 tutorial that did what I wanted: a multi select with auto-complete. This stores it serialised. No other way to search for IDs?

Comment: You'd just have to change how it saves the meta values, the Select2 is just helping you get them all, but as you process them for saving you'd have to make that adjustment.  There's multiple ways to search for the IDs the problem is that the serialized data could result in you getting incorrect results regardless of how you query for them.  :-(

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll look into that. Post as answer and I'll mark it

Comment: You're welcome.  Not going to post as answer as I haven't really helped you solve anything, just given some extra info.  Maybe someone'll swing by with something I haven't encountered yet that has an actually helpful answer.  :-)  Thank you though.